# Can you help me understand the grammar of this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> 外国人は無意識にやるけど、日本人は好きじゃないこういっていうのがあるんですね。

The translation is: there is an act that foreigners do unconsciously but Japanese people don't like.

The only part I don't understand is "こういっていうのが"
Could you please explain? Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: Now I'm intrigued. What is this act?

Comment: I believe I'm a native speaker but it certainly baffled me for a quite few seconds. They should really have spelled the word in kanji.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> こういっていうのがある

こうい should be [行為]{こうい}, "act, conduct".

～っていうの is a casual way of saying ～というもの (～と言う物 in kanji).